# Hosting updates repository. Qt Installer Framework repogen

Tags: qt, repository, hosting, qt-installer

I have created a project using Qt and I found the **Repogen** tool that cames with Qt.

[image]

In the official documentation says that I must host the repo in a server in order to receive updates or create an online installer. I tried using GitHub as a hosting but maintenance tool doesn't recognize it.

I added he repository url in the settings window of the maintenance tool pointing to the base repo path and then pointing directly to Updates.xml but the same error.

[image]

What kind of web server must I use to deliver the release files?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue, by creating a file service in Flask and using a free hosting to deliver files.
Seems like hosting in GitHub is not useful in that case.